# Visualize sum of column percentage for multiple response set variables

Tags: spss

I'm trying to understand how to visualise the sum of column percentages in some tabulations of multiple variables.

suppose that i have defined the variable $q12 as a multiple response set of categorical values of the variables sq12m1 sq12m2 sq12m3 sq12m4 sq12m5.

i could have cases with values only in sq12m1 or cases with values in all of those. 
if i want to see how many times any brand appear in any of those sq12m1 to sq12m5 i am using this:

```
CTABLES
  /VLABELS VARIABLES=$q12 DISPLAY=DEFAULT
  /TABLE $q12 [C][COUNT F40.0, COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.1]
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=$q12 ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE TOTAL=YES POSITION=AFTER 
    MISSING=EXCLUDE.
```

and it will generate this:

[image: frequencies]

how can i sum the column percentages? using this syntax the total is always 100%, i would like to visualise the sum (which in this case is 215.10%) which represents the average number of mentions...

do you know how to do it?
thanks!!!

Comment: If @horace_vr's post answers your question please mark it as the solution (this is how future users know the question is solved and that the answer is a valid solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one thing you need to change in your syntax, in the `/TABLE` sub-command:`COLPCT.RESPONSES.COUNT` instead of `COLPCT.COUNT`:

```
CTABLES
  /VLABELS VARIABLES=$q12 DISPLAY=DEFAULT
  /TABLE $q12 [C][COUNT F40.0, COLPCT.RESPONSES.COUNT PCT40.1]
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=$q12 ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE TOTAL=YES POSITION=AFTER 
    MISSING=EXCLUDE.
```